# Flow typedefs for Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, flowtype

Do flow type definitions for electron exist? As far as I know, electron has official typescript type definitions, but not flow type definitions. I spend some time searching and couldn't find anything useful. I'll probably just end up migrating the typedefs from typescript to flow, since both are very similar syntactically.